# C# join 2 Int16 into Int32

Tags: c#, join, integer

I ran into a dead-end for what I think should be a simple solution.
Basically, I have:

```
List<Uint16> header = new List<UInt16>();
```

Then I populate it with data but later I need to join a couple of elements into Int32 and I have no idea what is the best way to do it.  Are there any .NET calls I can make to join these two into Uint32?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "join"?

Comment: I would use "combine" instead of "join" (which usually associated with DB "join" operation)

Comment: Basically what the people below suggested.  Thank you for looking at this.

Comment: Side note: SYB, please avoid "thanks" in the post - note that commonly "thank you" notes will often be removed by someone along with other text not directly related to the question - feel free to check http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280141/is-it-recommended-to-leave-a-comment-that-signatures-are-removed/280158#280158 discussion whether one should leave comment about such removal or not.

Comment: @SYB Why didn't you choose the community's upvoted answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Bitwise Operators](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_bitwise_operators.htm):

```
    uint num = (uint)((header.ElementAt(0) << 16) | header.ElementAt(1));
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use bit shifting to do it:

```
var num = (uint)((header.ElementAt(0) << 16) | header.ElementAt(1));
```

That's assuming the element at 0 is most significant.

Comment: Thanks!  That's what I figured but was wondering if there's a better way.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Sort of off topic, but I was wondering if the cast to `uint` was nescessary, it is because if you do a bitshift, it's implicitly casted to `int32`.

Answer (score 1):

I think we also need to take care of the endianness of the system.

```
Stored value: 0x00000001

In memory representation:

       Memory Address

  Low                   High
   0       1      2      3
+------+------+------+------+
|  00  |  00  |  00  |  01  |      Big Endian Representation
+------+------+------+------+      stores the least significant byte
                                   in higher memory address. So we get
                                   0 in lower address.
  Low                   High
   0       1      2      3
+------+------+------+------+
|  01  | 00   |  00  |  00  |      Little Endian Representation
+------+------+------+------+      stores the least significant byte
                                   in lower memory address.
```

Therefore if we need to paste two `uint16` then first we need to understand the byte ordering.

```
uint16 val1, val2;

val1
+------+------+                       +------+------+
|  b1  |  b2  |             OR        |  b2  |  b1  |
+------+------+                       +------+------+

    (paste)                               (paste)

val2
+------+------+                       +------+------+
|  b3  |  b4  |             OR        |  b4  |  b3  |
+------+------+                       +------+------+

===============================+===============================
paste(val1,val2)               | paste(val2,val1)
   0      1      2      3      |    0      1      2      3
+------+------+------+------+  | +------+------+------+------+
|  b1  |  b2  |  b3  |  b4  |  | |  b4  |  b3  |  b2  |  b1  |
+------+------+------+------+  | +------+------+------+------+
     val1           val2       |      val2           val1
         LITTLE Endian                     BIG Endian
```

Therefore the byte ordering needs to be considered.

To check if the Endinness of the system you can use

```
endian = (((char *)&x)[0]) ? 0 : 1;
```

Where `0` is Little and `1` is Big. (I am not explaining this here).

Depending on this output you can use the `paste` function to get the `uint16`s pasted.

For completeness sake I am writing the paste function.

```
uint32 paste (uint16 n1, uint16 n2)
{
  return ((uint32) n1 << 16)| (uint) n2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by join them you mean use one Uint16 as the lowest 16 bits of a 32 bit Uint and the other as the highest 16 bits then you can use bit-wise arithmetic and shifting. Something like:

```
Uint16 u1;
Uint16 u2;
Uint32 = (Uint32)u1 << 16 | (Uint32)u2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function get_DWord(ByVal D1 As Short, ByVal D2 As Short) As Integer
    Dim Bits As String = Convert.ToString(D1, 16)
    Dim length As Integer = Bits.Length
    If length < 4 Then
        For I As Integer = 0 To 4 - length
            Bits = "0" & Bits
        Next
    End If
    Dim Bits2 As String = Convert.ToString(D2, 16)
    Dim No As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Bits2 & Bits, 2)
    Return No
End Function
```